# Regular expression for letter special character with numberL

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

looking for regular expression for specific alphanumeric as below:
Jan.19 - Feb.20

if string contains that data then return true...

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Do you mean "MMM.DD - MMM.DD" (where MMM is month and DD is day)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of REGEX, you can split the string on `-` and then try parsing each part with `DateTime.TryParseExact` with format `MMM.dd`. Validating DateTime with Regex is generally a bad idea. You can have a method like:

```
public bool IsValid(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        return false;
    string[] array = str.Split('-');
    if (array.Length != 2)
        return false;
    DateTime temp;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(array[0].Trim(), "MMM.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out temp))
        return false;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(array[1].Trim(), "MMM.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out temp))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Call it like:

```
    string str = "Jan.19 - Feb.20";
    Console.WriteLine(IsValid(str));
```

Comment: @user1893874, you are welcome, I see that you haven't accepted any answer so far, please see [How does accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)